# Identify dropouts from one vector into another in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors - the second one is like the first except some elements have dropped out. Sample data:

```
set.seed(31031966)
s1 = sample(10,20,TRUE)
s2=s1[-sample(20,5)]
s1
## [1] 6 2 3 2 7 4 9 5 9 6 6 9 4 6 8 2 5 7 4 8
s2
## [1] 6 2 7 9 5 9 6 6 9 6 8 2 5 7 8
```

What I want is the 5 (in this case) positions in `s1` that are missing in `s2`. So where the spaces are:

```
s1: 6 2 3 2 7 4 9 5 9 6 6 9 4 6 8 2 5 7 4 8
s2: 6 2     7   9 5 9 6 6 9   6 8 2 5 7   8
```

ie 3,4,6,13,19.

There's some ambiguity where there's repeated values, one of which is missing, since you don't know if the missing one is the first or last. I don't really care how that's resolved (in the real application its not much of a problem)

My thinking is a loop that gets the length of the matching elements starting at the first, then notes that, then continues from the next position, but its a bit messy and loopy and not very R-ish. Better methods?

And no code golf please!

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me, (unsure what code golf is):

```
# intialize counters    
missings <- integer(length(s1)-length(s2))
j <- 1
k <- 1
# loop
for(i in seq_along(s1)) {
  if(s1[i] == s2[j]){
    j <- j +1
  }
  else {
    missings[k] <- i
    k <- k + 1
    # stop the loop if missings is filled up
    if(k > length(missings)) break
  }
}
```

One nice feature of this is that you can check the missings object at the end to make sure it is filled in.

Comment: "Code golf" is the game where you try and solve a programming problem in as few characters as possible, leading to horribly obfuscated code. There's a whole SE site devoted to it!

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the description of code golf. Another checking method would be `any(missings == 0)`, since the missings should be positions in a vector (non-zero in R) and `integer(length=n)` creates a vector of length n filled with 0s.

Comment: I do feel there could be a more efficient solution with a `1:nmissings` loop rather than `1:length(s1)`. I wait...